# aui:form with many aui:button

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui

I am trying to develop an aui:form with three aui:button this way...

```
<portlet:actionURL name="generateRule" var="generateRuleURL"/>
<portlet:actionURL name="generateRuleAnd" var="generateRuleAndURL"/>
<portlet:actionURL name="generateRuleOr" var="generateRuleOrURL"/>

<aui:form action="<%= generateRuleURL.toString() %>" method="post">
<aui:fieldset column="false">
<aui:select name="FirstRuleElement" >
<aui:option value="Age">
<liferay-ui:message key="Age" />
</aui:option>
<aui:option value="Country">
<liferay-ui:message key="Country" />
</aui:option>
<aui:option value="Direction">
<liferay-ui:message key="Direction" />
</aui:option>
</aui:select>
<aui:select name="FirstRuleAttribute" >
<aui:option value="Age">
<liferay-ui:message key="Age" />
</aui:option>
<aui:option value="Country">
<liferay-ui:message key="Country" />
</aui:option>
<aui:option value="Direction">
<liferay-ui:message key="Direction" />
</aui:option>
</aui:select>
</aui:fieldset>
<aui:fieldset column="false">
<aui:button-row>
<aui:button type="submit" value="End" />

<aui:button type="submit" value="And"
onClick="<%= generateRuleAndURL.toString()%>" />

<aui:button type="submit" value="Or"
onClick="<%= generateRuleOrURL.toString()%>" />
</aui:button-row>
</aui:fieldset>
</aui:form>
```

And I want to execute different methods from the Portlet, depending on the button pressed...

```
public void generateRule(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
public void generateRuleAnd(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
public void generateRuleOr(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
```

Using this function for retrieving the data...

```
request.getParameter("FirstRuleElement")
```

But by doing click on the And and Or buttons I don't get the request parameters of the form.

Do you know how I can solve this??

Thank you,
Oriol

Comment: can you try replacing 'onClick="<%= generateRuleOrURL.toString()%>" />' with 'href=<%= generateRuleOrURL%>' and 'type="submit"' with 'type="button"'

Comment: That doesn't work, The request.getParameter parameters are null.

Comment: AUI button onClick: javascript code to be executed when clicking on the button. If this attribute starts with http://, the button will take you to that page when the user clicks on it. Now as you have provided urls in onclick it will take to that url[starting with http://], but form will not get submitted. You can write some js code that called up on onclick which sets required url in action of form and submit it.

Comment: Can you show me a sample of that js, please?

Answer (score 1):

Instead this

```
<aui:button type="submit" value="And"
onClick="<%= generateRuleAndURL.toString()%>" />

<aui:button type="submit" value="Or"
onClick="<%= generateRuleOrURL.toString()%>" />
```

, you can use below with javascript.

```
<aui:button type="submit" value="And"
onClick="javascript:submitTheForm('<%= generateRuleAndURL.toString()%>')" />
<aui:button type="submit" value="Or"
onClick="javascript:submitTheForm('<%=generateRuleOrURL.toString()%>')" />

<script>
function submitTheForm(url){
    document.forms['<portlet:namespace/>myform'].action=url;
    document.forms['<portlet:namespace/>myform'].submit();
}
</script>
```

Give name attribute as myForm for aui:form.

HTH

Comment: By clicking to one of the buttons I get these URL... http://localhost:8080/web/guest/%3C%=generateRuleOrURL.toString()%%3E I think the document.forms is not generating a good one. Im implementing the form in a file called view.jsp

Answer (score 0):

This is my code in view.jsp under the docroot folder.

```
<portlet:defineObjects />

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="<%= themeDisplay.isSignedIn() %>">
        <aui:form action="<%= generateRuleURL.toString() %>" method="post">
            <aui:fieldset column="false">
            <aui:select name="FirstRuleElement" >
                <aui:option value="Age">
                    <liferay-ui:message key="Age" />
                </aui:option>
                <aui:option value="Country">
                    <liferay-ui:message key="Country" />
                </aui:option>
                <aui:option value="Direction">
                    <liferay-ui:message key="Direction" />
                </aui:option>
            </aui:select>
            <aui:select name="FirstRuleAttribute" >
                <aui:option value="Age">
                    <liferay-ui:message key="Age" />
                </aui:option>
                <aui:option value="Country">
                    <liferay-ui:message key="Country" />
                </aui:option>
                <aui:option value="Direction">
                    <liferay-ui:message key="Direction" />
                </aui:option>
            </aui:select>
            <aui:select name="Operator" >
                <aui:option value="=">
                    <liferay-ui:message key="=" />
                </aui:option>
                <aui:option value=">">
                    <liferay-ui:message key=">" />
                </aui:option>
                <aui:option value="<">
                    <liferay-ui:message key='"\<"' />
                </aui:option>
                <aui:option value=">=">
                    <liferay-ui:message key=">=" />
                </aui:option>
                <aui:option value="<=">
                    <liferay-ui:message key="<=" />
                </aui:option>
            </aui:select>
            </aui:fieldset>
            <aui:fieldset column="false">
            <aui:input cssClass="lfr-textarea-container" name="ruleDefinition" style="height: 75px; width: 100%;" type="textarea" value="" wrap="off" />
            <aui:button-row>

                <portlet:actionURL name="generateRule" var="generateRuleURL"/>
                <aui:button type="button" value="End" onClick="<%= generateRuleURL.toString()%>" />

                <portlet:actionURL name="generateRule" var="generateRuleAndURL"/>
                <aui:button type="button" value="And" onClick="<%= generateRuleAndURL.toString()%>" />

                <portlet:actionURL name="generateRule" var="generateRuleOrURL"/>
                <aui:button type="button" value="Or" onClick="<%= generateRuleOrURL.toString()%>" />

                </aui:button-row>
            </aui:fieldset>
        </aui:form>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <div class="portlet-msg-info">
            <aui:a href="<%= themeDisplay.getURLSignIn() %>" label="sign-in-to-your-account" />
        </div>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```